# Creating CSV from PHP data File not closing

Tags: php, csv, export

I have a php file which creates a CSV file... however.  The contents of the CSV file also include the entire html page as well.

Here's the result:

```
Number, Access Code, Date
1,  1BIs1B1165n8xba,    29/01/2016
2,  1BIPa%1166vwG&M,    29/01/2016
3,  1BIKES11677GhK0,    29/01/2016
4,  1BIX$T11682w&&@,    29/01/2016
5,  1BIq2N1169npOn5,    29/01/2016
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html  dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">       
<head>      
...
...
...
</html>
```

Here's the code.

```
ob_clean();
$filename="export.csv";
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename);    

if(isset($associated_array['0'])) {
      $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
      fputcsv($fp, array_keys($associated_array['0']));
      foreach($associated_array AS $values){
         fputcsv($fp, $values);
      }
      fclose($fp);
}
ob_flush();
```

I've closed the file and I've flushed the buffer so where have I gone wrong please?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Same as with exit() I get the scripts at the top of the page.

Comment: ob_end_clean() as opposed to just ob_clean() seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the csv file to the client then you should exit your script after delivering data.

```
...
ob_flush();
exit();
```

If you don't `exit()` or `die()` any output of your script will be added to the csv file at client side.

Comment: Hi maxhb - thanks for a quick response.   That's worked.... partly.   For some reason I cannot fathom it is still including the text of scripts on the page:

`<script src="../../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
<script>   
function printDiv(divName) {  
...
...
 
}  
</script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {   
...
...
});   
</script>  
  
Number, Access Code, Date
1, 1BI@N%1238vb@y1, 29/01/2016
2, 1BIN#n1239cI&83,29/01/2016
3, 1BI@tw1240y@&q%, 29/01/2016
4, 1BI&gF12416h@AC ,  29/01/2016
5, 1BIi8Y1242j$map,    29/01/2016
`

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Any text your script outputs will be part of your csv. Prevent any output in case of csv export. Best option is to put export in an external file and reference that file via a download link.

Comment: OK Even more confused now.  The code works on my testing server but just appears on screen with the production server.

Can anyone suggest why this might be please?